# Pure javascript drag not smooth on iPad

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad

I am trying to drag a div (`#drag`) in it's parent (`#container`) with **pure javascript only**. 
(*Only need to work on iPad*).

I wrote a script that work fine when I use it in Chrome with *"Emulate touch events"* turned on, 
but on a real iPad, as soon as I start dragging a little fast the div stop following.

I thought my finger might get out of the element when I move too fast, 
so I set the `addEventListner` on the body instead of the div, but still the same.

Anyone have an idea why? And how to make it work smoothly on iPad?

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kxrEZ/

**Javascript**

```
var dom = {
    container: document.getElementById("container"),
    drag: document.getElementById("drag"),
}
var container = {
    x: dom.container.getBoundingClientRect().left,
    y: dom.container.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    w: dom.container.getBoundingClientRect().width,
    h: dom.container.getBoundingClientRect().height
}
var drag = {
    w: dom.drag.offsetWidth,
    h: dom.drag.offsetHeight
}

target = null;

document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, false);
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, false);
document.body.addEventListener('touchend', handleTouchEnd, false);

function handleTouchStart(e) {
    if (e.touches.length == 1) {
        var touch = e.touches[0];
        target = touch.target;
    }
}
function handleTouchMove(e) {
    if (e.touches.length == 1) {
        if(target ===  dom.drag) {
            moveDrag(e);
        }
    }
}
function handleTouchEnd(e) {
    if (e.touches.length == 0) { // User just took last finger off screen
        target = null;
    }
}

function moveDrag(e) {
    var touch = e.touches[0];
    var posX = touch.pageX - container.x - drag.w / 2;
    var minX = 0;
    var maxX = container.w - drag.w;
    if(posX < minX) {posX = minX;} 
    else if(posX > maxX) {posX = maxX;}
    var posY = touch.pageY - container.y - drag.h / 2;
    var minY = 0;
    var maxY = container.h - drag.h;
    if(posY < minY) {posY = minY;} 
    else if(posY > maxY) {posY = maxY;}
    dom.drag.style.left = posX + "px";
    dom.drag.style.top = posY + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider moving a lot of the variables you're using in `moveDrag` to be in a static memory pool (see: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/static-mem-pools/), since that function will be called quite often. Also, changing offset using `style.left` and `style.top` requires a reflow with each finger move - I'd suggest trying using render transforms during the move and then updating the styles only in `handleTouchEnd`